# Two duration widgets for a break timer, with ± buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

I'm sure I can optimise this code, but I can't find how in order to be generic. I'm not sure that `.parent` and `.child` combination is good in the long term here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lengthInit = $("#lengthSession").text();
  $("#timer").text(lengthInit);
  $("#dimBreak").click(function() {
    dimLength();
  });
  $("#augBreak").click(function() {
    augLength();
  });
  $("#dimSession").click(function() {
    dimLengthSession();
  });
  $("#augSession").click(function() {
    augLengthSession();
  });
});

function dimLength() {
  var length = parseInt($("#lengthBreak").text());
  length = length - 1;
  $("#lengthBreak").text(length);
}

function augLength() {
  var length = parseInt($("#lengthBreak").text());
  length += 1;
  $("#lengthBreak").text(length);
}

function dimLengthSession() {
  var length = parseInt($("#lengthSession").text());
  length = length - 1;
  $("#lengthSession").text(length);
}

function augLengthSession() {
  var length = parseInt($("#lengthSession").text());
  length += 1;
  $("#lengthSession").text(length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="rowTime">
    <div class="inputTime">
      <h2 class="titre">Break length</h2>
      <button class="boutons" id="dimBreak">-</button>
      <span class="length" id="lengthBreak">5</span>
      <button class="boutons" id="augBreak">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inputTime">
      <h2 class="titre">Session length</h2>
      <button class="boutons" id="dimSession">-</button>
      <span class="length" id="lengthSession">25</span>
      <button class="boutons" id="augSession">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for translating (some of) the symbols to English. Unfortunately, my fellow moderator pointed out that it was a mistake on my part to suggest to translate, and I agree (see our discussion in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25810741#25810741)). No need to touch this anymore, this is just for your information, and for the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Extract common logic to helper method

These functions have duplicate logic, but different data:

```
function augLength() {
  var length = parseInt($("#lengthBreak").text());
  length += 1;
  $("#lengthBreak").text(length);
}

function augLengthSession() {
  var length = parseInt($("#lengthSession").text());
  length += 1;
  $("#lengthSession").text(length);
}
```

A simple improvement is to extract the common logic to a helper method:

```
function inc(selector) {
  var length = parseInt($(selector).text());
  length += 1;
  $(selector).text(length);
}

function augLength() {
  inc("#lengthBreak");
}

function augLengthSession() {
  inc("#lengthSession");
}
```

#### Parsing an int

Instead of:

> ```
>   var length = parseInt($(selector).text());
> ```

Always when using `parseInt`, you should specify a radix parameter to indicate the *base*, for example for base-10:

```
  var length = parseInt($(selector).text(), 10);
```

And, what if the text cannot be parsed? It's good to make it default to something, say, 0, which you can achieve simply with:

```
  var length = parseInt($(selector).text(), 10) || 0;
```

#### DOM lookups are expensive

Instead of:

```
function inc(selector) {
  var length = parseInt($(selector).text(), 10) || 0;
  length += 1;
  $(selector).text(length);
}
```

It's better to do the DOM lookup once and reuse:

```
function inc(selector) {
  var dom = $(selector);
  var length = parseInt(dom.text(), 10) || 0;
  length += 1;
  dom.text(length);
}
```

#### Extracting more common logic

The `inc` helper can be extended to take care of the decrements too, by adding a second parameter:

```
function inc(selector, increment) {
  var dom = $(selector);
  var length = parseInt(dom.text(), 10) || 0;
  length += increment;
  dom.text(length);
}

function augLength() {
  inc("#lengthBreak", 1);
}

function augLengthSession() {
  inc("#lengthSession", 1);
}

function dimLength() {
  inc("#lengthBreak", -1);
}

function dimLengthSession() {
  inc("#lengthSession", -1);
}
```

#### Functions as parameters

You can do without the `augLength`, `dimLength`, `augLengthSession`, `dimLengthSession` functions, if you like, by using another helper that returns a function:

```
function makeIncrementer(selector, increment) {
  return function () { inc(selector, increment); };
}
```

Which then you can call directly from the `ready` block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lengthInit = $("#lengthSession").text();
  $("#timer").text(lengthInit);
  $("#dimBreak").click(makeIncrementer('#lengthBreak', -1));
  $("#augBreak").click(makeIncrementer('#lengthBreak', 1));      
  $("#dimSession").click(makeIncrementer('#lengthSession', -1));
  $("#augSession").click(makeIncrementer('#lengthSession', 1));
});
```

Comment: Impressive answer, by its quickness and its details! Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this question as [html5](/questions/tagged/html5), I think that it deserves a review taking HTML5 into account.  HTML5 has an [`<input type="number">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) input type that is designed just for this purpose.  You should use it because:

- It's semantically relevant.  The whole widget is represented in HTML as just one element.
- It provides a standard DOM interface through which your code can interact with the field.
- **You get all of the functionality that you implemented for free!**
- It results in a better user experience.  For example, if you click and hold one of the arrows, it would continue to increment or decrement.
- Out of the box, it would blend in with the look-and-feel of the user's desktop.
- The spec reminds you that you can set options like a `min="0"` attribute that would be applicable to a timer.
- It would be trivial to change it to, say, an `<input type="range">`, if you wanted to.

It's just this simple:

```css
fieldset {
    border: none;
}
label {
    display: block;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="lengthBreak">Break length</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="5" id="lengthBreak">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="lengthSession">Session length</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="25" id="lengthSession">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Note that I have replaced your `<div>`s and `<h2>`s with more semantically relevant `<fieldset>`s and `<label>`s.

---

What if you need it to work on a browser that doesn't support HTML5?  What if you don't like the way the widget looks?  Then you can use a shim to make it work the way you want.  For example, you can use jQuery UI to customize the look.

I'd much rather maintain this little bit of non-critical JavaScript code than implement the widget from scratch.  An additional benefit is that it integrates well with the jQuery philosophy — just one call to `$('input[type=number]').mySpinner()` instantiates both widgets.

```js
$.widget('custom.mySpinner', $.ui.spinner, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super('_create');
        $(this.element).attr('type', 'text');
    },
});

$(function() {
    $('input[type=number]').mySpinner();
});
```

```css
fieldset {
    border: none;
}
label {
    display: block;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* jQuery UI spinner visual customization */
.ui-spinner-button {
    height: 100% !important;
}
.ui-spinner-input {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
.ui-spinner-down {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="lengthBreak">Break length</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="5" id="lengthBreak">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="lengthSession">Session length</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="25" id="lengthSession">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```